# Run multiple word commands as variable

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I get some commands from file, and if they fulfil some conditions they are run.
Let say the command that is read from file is `$command`.

```
...
if [ $doCmd -eq 1 ]
then
   $command
   doCmd=0
   break
fi
...
```

The script is okay with single word commands like `ls`. But multiple word commands like `ls -l` or `echo "test"` cause this error:

```
x.sh: line x: ls -l: command not found
```

What is the right way to achieve? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your shell doesn't split variables in the open with IFS, $command won't expand to two aguments (ls and -l) which would interpret "ls -l" to be the single name of the command itself. If you're using bash you could use arrays instead. And also it's always good to place variables around quotes:

```
command=(ls -l)
if [ "$doCmd" -eq 1 ]
then
   "${command[@]}"
   doCmd=0
   break
fi
```

And further have better conditional expressions with:

```
if [[ doCmd -eq 1 ]]
```

Or conditional arithmetic:

```
if (( doCmd == 1 ))
```

Eval could actually be an option but it's dangerous since it dooesn't only reintrepret the command but the shell's general syntax as well.

```
if [ "$doCmd" -eq 1 ]
then
   eval "$command"
   doCmd=0
   break
fi
```

Comment: `eval` worked, thanks. I use `IFS` to split the string by ':' in file and retrieve the command to run.  I think that may cause not to split `$command` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes help.

Here's an example in the terminal, you can take it from here to get it to work in a script:

```
$ c='ls -l'
$ $c
total 168
drwx------+   4 ray  staff    136 Aug  3 14:27 Desktop
drwx------+  11 ray  staff    374 Jul 17 15:56 Documents
.
.
.
```

Comment: I've tried that. It works on command line. But same error occurs when trying to run after reading the command from file.